# shiny: passing reactiveValues to conditionalPanel

Tags: javascript, r, shiny

Can I pass a reactiveValues to a conditionalPanel's condition? If so, how?

Here is what I have tried in the conditionalPanel ui.R:

```
conditionalPanel(condition = "values.cond == 0", etc.
```

where I have defined `values$cond` in server.R:

```
values <- reactiveValues(cond = 0)
```

I have also tried alternatives like `"values.cond == true"`, without success.

```
library("shiny")
runGist("https://gist.github.com/anonymous/8281021")
```

See the code:

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/8281021

Comment: Note that I have a workaround for the app I posted, namely using the condition `condition = "input.action % 2 == 0"`, so my question is really restricted to this: can I pass `values$cond` to conditionalPanel, yes or no? Thanks!

Comment: I think you are asking whether reactive values are exposed to the client side. With the exception of input and output objects I dont think they are.

Comment: I see, and is there a simple way to pass reactiveValues$cond to an output$cond2 that the conditionalPanel would read? like via renderText or renderPrint or some other way? Thanks!

Comment: You could pass it in this manner or you could look to execute a java script call using for example `session$sendCustomMessage`

Comment: well thanks jd, I'll look into that (can't find an awful lot on google at this time)!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As @jdharrison pointed out, you have the problem, that you have reactive `values` or any other data on the server side and the conditional panel is a JS condition + some HTML on the client side. Hence, if you want to dynamically update the JS condition according to some value you calculated on the server side, you need to get the data from the server to the client. I think what you could do is use an still undocumented feature of shiny to pass custom data from the server to the client. I wrote a blog post on how to do that: http://ryouready.wordpress.com/2013/11/20/sending-data-from-client-to-server-and-back-using-shiny/

I guess you could use that approach to dynamically update the JS panel condition. You would need to write a JS function that does this after the data has been passed. So this boils down to replacing the `data-display-if` attribute of the `conditionalPanel` output with the values you want.

**Another idea**: If your UI strongly depends on calculations on the server side you may want to consider creating the (sidebar) content dynamically using `renderUI`.

**EDIT**: Btw, that's what @jdharrison referred to in his second comment.

Comment: Great blog post, thanks, I will need a while to process it ;-) The bottom line for me right now is to forget about using reactiveValues in a conditionalPanel.

Answer (score 10):

You can also do it by rendering text.

UI:

```
shinyUI(
  fluidPage(
    # Application title
    titlePanel("Test"),

    sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
        actionButton("ShowCond", "Show Conditional Panel"),
        conditionalPanel(
          condition = "output.test=='5'",
          actionButton("CheckFile", "Check file")
        )
      ),
      mainPanel(
        verbatimTextOutput("test")
      )
    )
  )
)
```

Server:

```
shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  var <- eventReactive(input$ShowCond, {
    5
  })

  output$test <- renderText({
    var()
  })
})
```

The catch is here that it doesn't work without the verbatimTextOutput. You need to include it somewhere on your UI side. However, you could reuse it as a message.

### EDIT:

It is also possible without the verbatimtext. By default Shiny suspends all output when they are not displayed. However, this can be changed by setting the following option for a specific output variable:

```
outputOptions(output, "test", suspendWhenHidden=FALSE)
```

In this case, there is no more need to use verbatimtext (and the corresponding rendertext).

Source: https://shinydata.wordpress.com/2015/02/02/a-few-things-i-learned-about-shiny-and-reactive-programming/#use-of-isolate-to-prevent-accidental-dependencies

Answer (score 2):

Based on the above I found a work-around by using both a `reactiveVal` (for use else where in your app) and writing it to output like suggested above.

```
your_reactive <- reactiveVal(NULL)

# Read input csv file
output$your_output <- eventReactive(TRUE, {
 
  out <- ""
      
  your_reactive(out) # update server side reactive
  
  return(out)
  
  })

# Make it available on client side
outputOptions(output, "your_output", suspendWhenHidden = FALSE)
```

In your ui you can now access `output.your_output`.