# Accessing a value from Server.R into .js file

Tags: javascript, r, shiny

I think's it's quite an easy one but I can't find a way to solve it myself.
I'd like to access the value of a variable in my Server.R file (I'm using Shiny) in my javascript file. My var "i" in myFile.js should take the value of my R variable "number". How should I proceed ?

Example :

**Server.R**

```
...
number <- 5
...
```

**myFile.js**

```
...
var i = ??? // var i = number *is not working* 
...
```

Thanks for your help,

Matt

Comment: Only variables assigned to `input` and `output` are accessible from javascript. You would need to pass them using something like `session$sendCustomMessage`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20948302/shiny-passing-reactivevalues-to-conditionalpanel

Comment: Thanks a lot @jdharrison, it works when I add the following code in myFile.js :  

var i ;  
Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler("myCallbackHandler",  
 function(number) {  
  i = number;  
 }  
);

Comment: Happy to help ...  maybe add that as an answer

Comment: My bad, it's not working :/.

Comment: If you give a minimal reproducible example of what you are trying to achieve it will be easier to help

Comment: This time, it's ok :). Can't give easily a minimal reproducible example, but this topic deals with an easy one : http://ryouready.wordpress.com/2013/11/20/sending-data-from-client-to-server-and-back-using-shiny/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to jdharrison, it works when I add the following code in myFile.js :

**Server.R**

```
number <- 5
observe({
   session$sendCustomMessage(type='myCallbackHandler', number) 
})
```

**myFile.js**

```
var i ;
Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler("myCallbackHandler",     
    function(number) {
     i = number;
    }
);
```

**var i** now takes the value 5 in my javascript file.