# How Do I Get a ConditionalPanel to Display with a Parameter Passed from the Server?

Tags: r, shiny

I have a problem with conditionalPanel displaying conditional on a parameter passed by the server via output to the ui.

Here is my toy program:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
    # This is Jeff's conditionalPanel 
    conditionalPanel(
    condition = "output.DataModelJeff > 0",
    div(style="color: rgb(0,135,73); text-align:center; font-size: 24px; background-color: rgb(0,135,73)",
       textOutput("DataModelJeff"),
    ),
     div(style="color: white; text-align:center; font-size: 24px; background-color: rgb(0,135,73)",
       p("Hi"),
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  DataModelJeff <- 194
  output$DataModelJeff <- renderText({DataModelJeff})
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

This functions properly and displays 1) the conditional panel and 2) the condition number.

This toy program

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
    # This is Jeff's conditionalPanel 
    conditionalPanel(
    condition = "output.DataModelJeff > 0",
    # div(style="color: rgb(0,135,73); text-align:center; font-size: 24px; background-color: rgb(0,135,73)",
    #    textOutput("DataModelJeff"),
    # ),
    div(style="color: white; text-align:center; font-size: 24px; background-color: rgb(0,135,73)",
       p("Hi"),
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  DataModelJeff <- 194
  output$DataModelJeff <- renderText({DataModelJeff})
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

does **not** function "properly" and displays neither the conditional panel nor the condition number.

Here is a snippet of the real program:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
conditionalPanel(
  # This is Jeff's conditionalPanel 
  condition = "input.cond1 == 'event1' && input.cond2 > 0 && output.DataModelJeff > 0",
      div(style="color: white; text-align:center; font-size: 24px; background-color: rgb(0,135,73)",
          textOutput("DataModelJeff"),
      ),
      div(style="color: white; text-align:center; font-size: 24px; background-color: rgb(0,135,73)",
          p("Some text")),
      br(),
}
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  DataModelJeff <- 194
  output$DataModelJeff <- renderText({DataModelJeff})
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

It does **not** function "properly" and displays neither the conditional panel nor the condition number.

This

```
ui <- fluidPage(
conditionalPanel(
  # This is Jeff's conditionalPanel 
  condition = "input.cond1 == 'event1' && input.cond2 > 0", # && output.DataModelJeff > 0",
      div(style="color: white; text-align:center; font-size: 24px; background-color: rgb(0,135,73)",
          textOutput("DataModelJeff"),
      ),
      div(style="color: white; text-align:center; font-size: 24px; background-color: rgb(0,135,73)",
          p("Some text")),
      br(),
}
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  DataModelJeff <- 194
  output$DataModelJeff <- renderText({DataModelJeff})
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

displays the conditional panel and conditional number but is useless to me, as I have another conditional panel that should **not** display if DataModelJeff != 194.  (I just picked 194 out a hat; V194 is The Green Hornet's license plate number.)

Could someone explain to me why the real program does not display the conditional panel (I don't need the conditional number displayed but am not averse to displaying it if it should be "necessary")?

Thanks much in advance.

Comment: The widget that controls the display of the `conditionalPanel` must be rendered.  See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21609436/r-shiny-conditionalpanel-output-value).  Personally, I prefer to avoid `conditionalPanel` and use `uiOutput`/`renderUI` instead, because it romoves the extra level of complication caused by the interface between Shiny and JavaScript.  And, in this case, it removes the need to display the infomation that controls the panel.

Comment: You might want to check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38899895/9841389). In contrast to @Limey I prefer `conditionalPanel` over `renderUI` as it has a direct effect on the client-side (hiding/showing an element is faster than re-rendering it). From [mastering shiny](https://mastering-shiny.org/action-dynamic.html#dynamic-basics): `This is one of the downsides of renderUI(); relying on it too much can create a laggy UI.`

Comment: PS: Also check the section about hidden tabsetPanels as an alternative.

Comment: @ismirsehregal: I'm always happy to listen to a counter argument. :=)

Answer (score 0):

The "issue" in this case actually is a feature.

[Shiny is lazy](https://mastering-shiny.org/basic-reactivity.html#laziness). By default if an output isn't diplayed on the client it won't be rendered on the server to save resources (in your case `renderText` won't run - please see the `print` call in the code below) accordingly its value is not initialized when `conditionalPanel` is executed.

To opt-out of this behaviour we can set `suspendWhenHidden = FALSE` by calling `outputOptions`:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  # This is Jeff's conditionalPanel 
  conditionalPanel(
    condition = "output.DataModelJeff > 0",
    # div(style="color: rgb(0,135,73); text-align:center; font-size: 24px; background-color: rgb(0,135,73)",
    #    textOutput("DataModelJeff"),
    # ),
    div(style="color: white; text-align:center; font-size: 24px; background-color: rgb(0,135,73)",
        p("Hi"),
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  DataModelJeff <- 194
  output$DataModelJeff <- renderText({
    print("rendering DataModelJeff")
    DataModelJeff
  })
  outputOptions(output, "DataModelJeff", suspendWhenHidden = FALSE)
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

---

However, in my eyes a "cleaner" approach would be to separate the data handling (reactive) and its display (output):

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tabsetPanel(
    id = "switcher",
    type = "hidden",
    tabPanelBody(value = "gt0",
                 div(style = "color: white; text-align:center; font-size: 24px; background-color: rgb(0,135,73)", p("Hi"))
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  # separate data (reactive) and display (output) 
  DataModelJeff <- reactive({
    194
  })
  
  # output$DataModelJeff <- renderText({
  #   print("rendering DataModelJeff")
  #   DataModelJeff()
  # })
  # outputOptions(output, "DataModelJeff", suspendWhenHidden = FALSE)
  
  observe({
    if (DataModelJeff() > 0) {
      updateTabsetPanel(inputId = "switcher", selected = "gt0")
    } else {
      updateTabsetPanel(inputId = "switcher", selected = NULL)
    }
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Above I'm using a `tabsetPanel` for illustrative purposes, you can do the same with `conditionalPanel`.